# How to use external js files in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am trying to convert bootstrap 4 template into reactjs bootstrap is working fine but there are other javascript plugins also and I don't know how to use .
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If it is functions you are trying to use, have you tried using `window.extJSfunc()`? (With extJSfunc being the name of the function you need to use)

Comment: simple importing of that JS file doesnt work for you?

Comment: I have imported js file in index,html but it is not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i use external script that i add to react JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53396307/how-do-i-use-external-script-that-i-add-to-react-js)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update:** Please, don't mix jQuery and React. It could be difficult to handle the DOM and VirtualDOM. Just try it if you really need to:

Try to invoke the scripts and append it when componentDidMount at Root component. Here is a snippet:

```
//#Write some like this in the App.js for example, since it's the main component:
componentDidMount(){
    //An array of assets
    let scripts = [
        { src: "assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.js" },
        { src: "assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" },
        { src: "assets/vendor/jquery-placeholder/jquery.placeholder.js" },
        { src: "assets/javascripts/theme.js" },
        { src: "assets/javascripts/theme.custom.js" },
        { src: "assets/javascripts/theme.init.js" }
    ]
    //Append the script element on each iteration
    scripts.forEach(item => { 
        const script = document.createElement("script")
        script.src = item.src
        script.async = true
        document.body.appendChild(script)
    })    
 }
```

Comment: I guess it's better to use forEach rather than map: scripts.forEach(item => { ... })

Answer (score -3):

Include the script tag in your index.html

Let's say if you want to include JQuery in your ReactJs app

Include following in **index.html**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Use this in following code and it works well

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.callJquery = this.callJquery.bind(this);
  }

  callJquery(){
    window.$("#sample").click(function(){
      alert("Text: Button Clicked");
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div id="sample" onClick={this.callJquery}> Hellow </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Similarly, you can use any library by including in index.html and then use it.