# how to force webpack to keep the dynamic import

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have this code

```
import('./myfile.js')
.then(m=>console.log(m.default))
.catch(err=>console.error(err))
```

webpack bundles "myfile.js", but I want to copy this file to 'dist' and import it dynamically, i.e. I want to avoid compiling this `import()` statement.

note that this code is a part of a function and the file 'myfile.js' is provided by a function argument, so I cannot add the path to the webpack's externals array.

**I tried the following approaches:**

- using webpac's magic comments `/* webpackIgnore: true, webpackMode: "lazy" */`
- provide a variable path

```
let file = 'myfile.js'
import('./' + file)
```

- provide the path as a function call

```
let getPath = path=>path
import(getPath('./myfile.js'))
```

- put the import statement inside a function

```
function load(path){
  return import('./' + path)
}

load('myfile.js')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic loading of external modules in webpack fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56691391/dynamic-loading-of-external-modules-in-webpack-fails)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @tevemadar. the answer you mentioned explains how webpack works with dynamic imports, but unfortunately, doesn't provide a solution to my use case.