# How to use a Grubhub link provided by Grubhub in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to add a button to my web app provided by a Grubhub in one of my React components using their link for food delivery but the button is not appearing on the screen.

I want to add button as shown in the code below inside my special component.

```
function Special() {

  return (

      <div class="gh-button-ifrm container" data-customer-id="xxxxx" data-restaurant-name="xxxxxxx" data-button-type="branded" data-button-color="red" data-button-size="large" data-env="xxx" data-url="xxxxxxx" data-tracking-id="xxxxxx" data-restaurant-address="xxxxxxx" data-version="xxx" data-link-type="xx" style= "margin-top: 20px;"></div>
<script src="https://gh-prod-nitrosites.s3.amazonaws.com/scripts/iframeLib.min.js"></script>

  );

export default Special;
```

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53396827/863110) answer

Comment: Glad to hear :) Good luck