# External script with classes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to embed an external map service into my React app. Their recommendation to integrate the API into a regular HTML web page looks like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//map.search.ch/api/map.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">new SearchChMap({center:[123456,987654],y:"-1m",poigroups:"default"});</script>
```

I tried to apply this in my `typescript` React component as follows:

```js
declare class SearchChMap {
  constructor(_: {})
}

// ...

<>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//map.search.ch/api/map.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">{new SearchChMap({ center: [123456, 987654], poigroups: "default" })}</script>
  {/* ... */}
</>
```

While this compiles, I receive the following runtime error: `ReferenceError: SearchChMap is not defined`.

What is the correct way of using legacy JavaScript classes from an externally hosted script in your React components?

### Update:

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62732602) to no avail, using the following code:

```js
componentDidMount(): void {
  const script1: HTMLScriptElement = document.createElement("script");
  script1.src = "//map.search.ch/api/map.js";
  script1.async = true;
  document.body.appendChild(script1);

  const script2: HTMLScriptElement = document.createElement("script");
  script2.text = 'new SearchChMap({center:[123456,987654],y:"-1m",poigroups:"default"});';
  script2.async = true;
  document.body.appendChild(script2);
}
```

This results in the exact same error message, just a few seconds later, since the scripts are added dynamically.

### Update 2:

Moving the object creation to `onload` as suggested by `AWolf` did the trick:

```js
componentDidMount(): void {
  const scriptTag: HTMLScriptElement = document.createElement("script");
  scriptTag.src = "//map.search.ch/api/map.js";
  document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);

  scriptTag.onload = () => {
    new SearchChMap({ center: this.props.center, container: this.props.containerId });
  };
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i use external script that i add to react JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53396307/how-do-i-use-external-script-that-i-add-to-react-js)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Please see my update in the question.

Comment: Adding the map object creation in the `onload` method of the script tag will help to fix the loading issue. The following [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/searchapi-usage-with-external-script-g87dv) is working.

Comment: Thanks @AWolf, this worked, as described in my update above. Feel free to turn your comment into an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the script tag to `public/index.html` and use it with `window.SearchChMap` or if you prefer to load it from your `componentDidMount` you can do it like in the snippet below (same code as in the following [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/searchapi-usage-with-external-script-g87dv)).

It is using `onload` of the appended script tag to delay the object creation until the new script is loaded.

The `useRef` is used so you can use the created object in other locations of your function (not used in the example).

The `useEffect` in the code is required to ensure that the DOM is ready before adding the tag. Same behavior as in class-based components with `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.
The return of the `useEffect` could be used to do cleanup e.g. `return () => { /* remove script tag & dispose the window.SearchChMap */}` (same as `componentWillUnmount`)

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default () => {
  const SearchMap = useRef(); // optional, but useful if the Map object is used after mounting
  useEffect(() => {
    const scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
    scriptTag.src = "//map.search.ch/api/map.js";
    document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);

    scriptTag.onload = () => {
      SearchMap.current = new window.SearchChMap({ center: "Zürich" });
    };
  }, [SearchMap]);

  return (
    <div
      id="mapcontainer"
      style={{ maxWidth: "500px", height: "400px", border: "2px inset #ccc" }}
    />
  );
};
```