# How to include external js files in an react component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, react-helmet

I am trying to insert some external js files in my react component. I tried to include them in a simple html file in script tags and it was working fine but how to do in react component.
How I included them in html page:-

```
<script src="js/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/eclipse");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/c_cpp");
</script>
<body>
   <div id="editor">
       //text to display
   </div>
</body>
```

`id="editor"` is defined in js files which is included in the script tags so main problem is how to include this in a react component. I have seen some results showing to use customReactHooks but no idea how to implement it . Any idea

Comment: you can use document.createElement to create a new script tag. And append it to the html when a certain component mounts

Comment: can you describe in detail @thealpha93

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use external script that I add to react JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53396307/how-do-i-use-external-script-that-i-add-to-react-js)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of npm library named react-script-tag

Comment: This answer is only minimal helpful. You could add an explanation or a little example to your answer to improve its quality. If you're doing it good enough, you may get some upvotes. Please see [answer] and edit your answer.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const loadScript = (callback) => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'path'; // path for your script
  script.id = 'some id';
  document.body.appendChild(script);

  script.onload = () => {
    if (callback) callback();
  };
}
```

call this function in the useEffect or componentDidMount of your react component

Comment: how to include the working of second script tag. Simply including them in above function is not working . @thealpha93