# Adding jquery code inside React Component

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

I'm trying to call a Jquery plugin within my React component but for some reason it isn't working.

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
state = {
    id: null
}
componentDidMount () {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/babel";
    script.src = "../assets/js/timeline/timeline.min.js";
    script.async = true;
    console.log('Script',script);
    document.onload = () => {
        $('.timeline').timeline({
        forceVerticalMode: 700,
        mode: 'horizontal',
        verticalStartPosition: 'left',
        visibleItems: 7
      });
      
    }
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

I'm trying to call the timeline function which is present in the timeline.min.js file which is present in my src folder for which I have added a reference in the code. Currently, I have a vertical timeline on the frontend but I want to change that to a horizontal timeline.
But is this the right way to call the jquery plugin? Am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: it looks like you're trying to run a timeline function before appending the actual timeline code to your dom, did you try running document.body.appendChild(script) before .timeline()?

also, when is the react code being run? make sure that code is not being executed after the document.onload event, since in that case everything in document.onload won't run.