# Error message when trying to link external JS file to react Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

When I try to link my main.js folder into my react component, I get this error message

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

I want implement the JS to the modals into my work section, I am having trouble doing that.  I am very new to React so I am not totally sure what the rules and best practices are.  I am tryint turn my old portfolio site into a new SPA site.

[image: Anonymous Function?]

Code:

```
// select the open-btn button
let openBtn = document.getElementById('open-btn');
// select the modal-background
let modalBackground = document.getElementById('modal-background');
// select the close-btn 
let closeBtn = document.getElementById('close-btn');

// shows the modal when the user clicks open-btn
openBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    modalBackground.style.display = 'block';
});

// hides the modal when the user clicks close-btn
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    modalBackground.style.display = 'none';
});

// hides the modal when the user clicks outside the modal
window.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    // check if the event happened on the modal-background
    if (event.target === modalBackground) {
        // hides the modal
        modalBackground.style.display = 'none';
    }
});

// select the open-btn button
let openBtn2 = document.getElementById('open-btn2');
// select the modal-background
let modalBackground2 = document.getElementById('modal-background2');
// select the close-btn 
let closeBtn2 = document.getElementById('close-btn2');

// shows the modal when the user clicks open-btn
openBtn2.addEventListener('click', function () {
    modalBackground2.style.display = 'block';
});

// hides the modal when the user clicks close-btn
closeBtn2.addEventListener('click', function () {
    modalBackground2.style.display = 'none';
});

// hides the modal when the user clicks outside the modal
window.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    // check if the event happened on the modal-background
    if (event.target === modalBackground2) {
        // hides the modal
        modalBackground2.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

React Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import toDoListApp from '../mockups/to-do-list-img..jpg';
import pokeMockup from '../mockups/mockup-poke.jpg';
import ExpatColMock from '../img/colombia_logo.png';
import DogAPIMock from '../mockups/mockup-doggie.gif';

import modals from '../js/main.js';





class Work extends Component {


  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <section>
          <div>
            {/* Modal Background and Modal */}
            <div className="mCustomScrollbar" data-mcs-theme="dark" id="modal-background">
              <div id="modal">
                <span id="close-btn">×</span>
                <img className="modal-img" src="mockups/mockup.png" alt="expatcolombia" />
                <h2 className="modal-title">Expat Colombia</h2>
                <div className="modal-text">
                  <h3>Description</h3>
                  <p>Expat Service for people moving to Colombia. They provide consultations, tours, and assist in housing.</p>
                  <h3>Dependencies</h3>
                  <p>HTML, CSS, Javascript</p>
                </div>
                <div className="buttons">
                  <a href="https://drxl95.github.io/Colombia/" target="_blank">Visit</a>
                  <a href="https://github.com/Drxl95/Colombia" target="_blank">Github</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            {/* Modal Background and Modal */}
            <div className="mCustomScrollbar2" data-mcs-theme="dark" id="modal-background2">
              <div id="modal2">
                <span id="close-btn2">×</span>
                <img className="modal-img2" src="mockups/poke-mockup.jpg" alt="expatcolombia" />
                <h2 className="modal-title">PokemonAPI</h2>
                <div className="modal-text2">
                  <h3>Description</h3>
                  <p>Pokemon-themed App with a that includes names, images, and stats of different Pokemons.</p>
                  <h3>Dependencies</h3>
                  <p>Javascript, JQuery, Ajax</p>
                </div>
                <div className="buttons2">
                  <a href="poke_demo.html" target="_blank">Demo</a>
                  <a href="https://github.com/Drxl95/PokemonAPI" target="_blank">Github</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <header className="ScriptHeader">
              <div>
                <h1 className="work-title">My Work</h1>
              </div>
            </header>
            <section id="work">
              {/*****Image size (height) is paramount to keep the photos formatted properly*****/}
              {/* Image row 1 */}
              <div className="row">
                <div className="column">
                  <div className="container">
                    <img src={toDoListApp} className="image" alt="to-do-list-api" />
                    <a href="https://github.com/Drxl95/To-Do-List" target="_blank">
                      <div className="overlay">
                        <div className="text">Simple jQuery To Do List App</div>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="column">
                  <a id="open-btn2">
                    <div className="container">
                      <img src={pokeMockup} className="image" alt="PokemanAPI" />
                      <div className="overlay">
                        <div className="text">Pokemon-themed API app <br /></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div className="column">
                  <a id="open-btn">
                    <div className="container">
                      <img src={ExpatColMock} className="image" alt="expatcolombia.com" />
                      <div className="overlay">
                        <div className="text">Expat Colombia</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div className="column">
                  <a href="https://github.com/Drxl95/DogAlbum" target="_blank">
                    <div className="container">
                      <img src={DogAPIMock} className="image" alt="dogAPI-mockup" />
                      <div className="overlay">
                        <div className="text">Dog Album API</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              {/* Image row 2 */}
              {/* <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="container">
          <img src="img/image-4.jpg" class="image">
          <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">Example 4</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="container">
          <img src="img/image-5.jpg" class="image">
          <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">Example 5</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="container">
          <img src="img/image-6.jpg" class="image">
          <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">Example 6</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div> */}
              {/* partial */}
            </section>
          </div>
        </section>
        <script src={modals}>

        </script>
      </>

    )
  }
}

export default Work
```

Comment: This may help..https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/how+to+import+external+js+file+in+react+js

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement that, like I said I am new to this

Comment: No issues @RDX10290. This question has been already answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/q/53396307/11045279.