How to Properly Load External Scripts in a React Application?
I'm trying to include external script files in my React project to use them in various parts of my code. I've created a ScriptLoader component to handle the loading of these script files, but I'm encountering an "Unexpected token '<'" error.
Desired Behavior:
I want the external JavaScript files to be loaded correctly without errors so they can be used in my React components.
Problem:
When I include the script files, I receive the following error in the browser console:
Unexpected token '<'
Here is the code for my App component:
import React from 'react';
import Layout from './components/Layout';
import Index from './pages/Index';
import ScriptLoader from './components/ScriptLoader';

var scripts = [
  "./rooteFile/assets/js/jquery.min.js",
  "./rooteFile/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js",
  "./rooteFile/assets/js/waves.js",
  "./rooteFile/assets/js/wow.min.js",
  "./rooteFile/assets/js/jquery.nicescroll.js",
  "./rooteFile/assets/js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js",
  "./rooteFile/assets/chat/moment-2.2.1.js",
  "./rooteFile/assets/jquery-sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js",

];

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Layout>
        <ScriptLoader scripts={scripts} />
        <Index />
      </Layout>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;


// Here is the code for my `ScriptLoader ` component:


import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

function loadScript(src) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;
    script.async = true;
    script.onload = resolve;
    script.onerror = reject;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  });
}

const ScriptLoader = ({ scripts }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    scripts.reduce((prev, src) => {
      return prev.then(() => loadScript(src));
    }, Promise.resolve());
  }, [scripts]);

  return null;
};

export default ScriptLoader;

What I've Tried:
Verifying that the paths are correct.
Confirming that the CSS files load correctly with the same paths.
Checking the network tab which shows that the requests for the JavaScript files are returning HTML.
What I Expect:
The external JavaScript files should be loaded without errors so that they can be utilized within my React components.
What Actually Happens:
I receive an "Unexpected token '<'" error indicating that the response contains HTML instead of the expected JavaScript.
What could be causing this issue, and how can I properly load the external script files in my React project?
this is my root file :

and this is response :

Console error:

Runtime Error


add full error text, and add prinscrin(If it's not difficult)

Can't you use import "./rooteFile/assets/js/jquery.min.js" for example ?

The question was edited and two pictures of the error were added. @SwaD

Yes, when I enter this address like this, it gives an error. @ArnaudFlaesch

Not really, it looks otherwise if  you have a root html file you could include the scripts in it. Does importing the files like this triggers an issue ?

I haven't added the scripts directly to the root HTML file. When I import the files this way, I get the  Unexpected token < error. Is there a way to correctly load these scripts within React components? @ArnaudFlaesch

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53396307/how-do-i-use-external-script-that-i-add-to-react-js

I tried this method too, unfortunately it didn't work. @ArnaudFlaesch

You said you're getting HTML instead of  the expected JS, what's inside the HTML in the network tab ?
